# I have a problem that whenever i press a button the previous button was being delivered for about 2 -3 seconds before its own value

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ros

so im developing an android controller so now when i press another button its calling the previous button that i pressed for about 2 -3 seconds before its own data

i was able to send single data for every button that's pressed and another data when its release.

```
upbtn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == ACTION_DOWN) {
                rosbridge.Publish("/set_velocity", nav_ctrl);
                nav_ctrl.linear.x = 0;
                nav_ctrl.angular.z = 0;
                return true;

            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                rosbridge.Publish("/set_velocity", nav_ctrl);
                nav_ctrl.linear.x = 0.6;
                nav_ctrl.angular.z = 0;


            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    downbtn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == ACTION_DOWN) {
                rosbridge.Publish("/set_velocity", nav_ctrl);
                nav_ctrl.linear.x = 0;
                nav_ctrl.angular.z = 0;

                return true;

            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                rosbridge.Publish("/set_velocity", nav_ctrl);
                nav_ctrl.linear.x = -0.6;
                nav_ctrl.angular.z = 0;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    leftbtn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == ACTION_DOWN) {
              rosbridge.Publish("/set_velocity", nav_ctrl);
                nav_ctrl.linear.x = 0;
                nav_ctrl.angular.z = 0;
                return true;

            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                rosbridge.Publish("/set_velocity", nav_ctrl);
                nav_ctrl.linear.x = 0;
                nav_ctrl.angular.z = 1.2;

            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    rightbtn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == ACTION_DOWN) {
                rosbridge.Publish("/set_velocity", nav_ctrl);
                nav_ctrl.linear.x = 0;
                nav_ctrl.angular.z = 0;

                return true;

            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                rosbridge.Publish("/set_velocity", nav_ctrl);
                nav_ctrl.linear.x = 0;
                nav_ctrl.angular.z = -1.2;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

i expect that the output should call its own value and not delay for about 2 -3 secs before publishing its own data.